# How to kill an activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a `splash screen`, a `GridView`, a `simple text view`.

On application start, I show the splash screen after which i call "finish()" to exit the activity and then start the "`GridView`" activity.

```
1st page: Grid View having 4 buttons, let's call it Home page..
2nd page: On click of 1st button, SAME grid view is called. But this time, there are 5 buttons.
3rd page: On click of 1st button, same grid view is called. This time there are 3 buttons.
4th page: On click of 1st button, it opens a simple text view, which has a text box and an "Home" button.
```

On home page, when i click the back button, I want the application to exit, or close...
But since the 1st, 2nd, 3rd page are still in the stack, I cannot just exit the application.

On my home screen, if i hit the "home" button of the tablet, the application exits. When i start the application again from the "Apps" option, the previously present screen is shown and not the splash screen!!!

I want it to show the splash screen.

Comment: good question if you dont mind then search in google for splash screen example.you can find your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call new screen using

```
Intent intent = new Intent(activity,secondActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
activity.startActivity(intent);
```

When you hit home button , application get resume. so next time it open the same page. for this use

```
@Override
protected void onRestart() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onRestart();
    startActivity(new Intent(Activity1.this,spalshscreen.class));
}
```

on restarting , you can also reset flag using `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` if activity is in stack.

Comment: Thanks, then i didn't know about the onRestart. The issue is solved. Thanks for commenting.

Comment: hey, sorry, am a bit busy wid dead lines. Will talk to you later?

Answer (score 2):

try to use `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` when you start the activity.

Comment: start your activity like this:Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Activity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);

Comment: It won't go to the 2nd page, which is the same "Grid View" but with different buttons...

Answer (score 1):

use Launch mode in manifest for that Activity as single Task

[Click Here to Get Uunderstanding For Launch Modes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode)

Comment: I don't want it to be single top.

Comment: use single Task and only best suitable way for what you desired is through lauch mode

Answer (score 1):

try this code in your activity -

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
   android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
}
```

When you exit from your application, your application process is not actually destroyed. If you destroy your process, all child processes(all your child threads) will be destroyed.

Comment: issue is already solved, i put a check mark on 1 of the answers above, but thank you :)